# A determinant made of $n \times n$ determinants.

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

I came across this problem, in a recent exam.

So I was given three matrices $$ A, B, C \in M_{n} (\mathbb{R}) $$ and that $$ 0 \in M_{n}(\mathbb{R}) $$ is the zero matrix.

Then I was also given the matrix $$ \Lambda = \begin{bmatrix} A & B \\ 0 & C\end{bmatrix} \in M_{2n} (\mathbb{R}) $$

I had to determine the formula of determinant of matrix $ \Lambda$ with determinants $ A$, $B$ and $C $ and then prove the latter.

I had the idea to use Gauss method in general and get a formula with that, but I had no time, and I think I wouldn't get anywhere with that. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are elementary matrices $E_1$ to $E_n$ such that $A$ = $E_1 \dotsb E_n R$ where $R$ is in RRE form.
 There are elementary matrices $\varepsilon_1$ to $\varepsilon_n$ such that $C = \varepsilon_1 \dotsb \varepsilon_n r$ where $r$ is in RRE form.
Form the matrices $E'_i$ in the following way: $E'_i = \begin{bmatrix} E_i & 0 \\ 0 & I\end{bmatrix}$ where $I$ is the identity matrix.
Form the matrices $\varepsilon'_i$ in the following way: $\varepsilon'_i = \begin{bmatrix} I & 0 \\ 0 & \varepsilon_i\end{bmatrix}$
Finally, notice that $\Lambda = E'_1 \dotsb E'_n \varepsilon_1 \dotsb \varepsilon_n \begin{bmatrix}R & * \\ 0 & r\end{bmatrix}$.

Now $\det \Lambda = \det(E'_1 \dotsb E'_n \varepsilon_1 \dotsb \varepsilon_n) \begin{vmatrix}R & * \\ 0 & r\end{vmatrix}$. But also notice that $R$ and $r$ are upper triangular matrices, which means that so is $\begin{bmatrix}R & * \\ 0 & r\end{bmatrix}$, and the determinant of an upper triangular matrix is the product of the entries on the diagonal. But all the diagonal entries are part of $R$ or $r$. So $\det \Lambda = \det(E'_1 \dotsb E'_n \varepsilon_1 \dotsb \varepsilon_n) \det(R) \det(r) = \det(E'_1 \dotsb E'_n R) \det(\varepsilon_1 \dotsb \varepsilon_n r) = \det(A)\det(C)$

Comment: A more detailed explanation would be helpful. How do you get $ det(B) $  to be irrelevant? And how can i prove this formula?

Comment: @user246608 Do you understand this edit?

Comment: I do understand most of it,but what is RRE form? I never came across it, during lectures?

Comment: @user246608 Reduced row echelon form. Have you come across that or row echelon form?

Comment: No i have not.  Maybe it is called different in my language. But this exercise is part of a subject: vectors and matrices. We were only basics in determinants and matrices. We didn't call anything "echelons"

Comment: @user246608 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form

Comment: Now i understand it. We didn't call it like that we just pointed it as pivoting the matrix when  we were solving linear systems. Now it's more understandable. And is this solution also a prove?or do I have to do it after this?

Comment: @user246608 I think it's a proof.

Comment: I think the same, because every operation was actually basically proven already by theorems and definitons. Thankyou for your answer. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 3):

Another hint, which works in greater generality (any commutative base ring): The determinant of $\Lambda$ is the sum of the terms $\left(\operatorname{sign}\sigma\right) \lambda_{1, \sigma\left(1\right)} \lambda_{2, \sigma\left(2\right)} \cdots \lambda_{2n, \sigma\left(2n\right)}$ over all permutations $\sigma$ of $\left\{1, 2, \ldots, 2n\right\}$ (where $\lambda_{i, j}$ means the $\left(i, j\right)$-th entry of $\Lambda$). However, the terms corresponding to some of these permutations $\sigma$ vanish; namely, this happens for every $\sigma$ for which some $i > n$ satisfies $\sigma\left(i\right) \leq n$ (because such a $\sigma$ picks out an entry from the $0$ block of the block matrix $\left[\begin{array}{cc} A & B \\ 0 & C\end{array}\right]$). What can you say about the remaining permutations?

Comment: Well reamining permutations are part of $ det (A) and det(C) $ or am i wrong?

Comment: Essentially yes. More precisely, they have the form "some permutation of $1, 2, \ldots, n$, followed by some permutation of $n+1, n+2, \ldots, 2n$".

Comment: So if i use this,what kind of formula shoudl i get? Because i need to script it in relation with det(A), det(B)  and det(C).

Comment: The product of the formula for $\det A$ with the formula for $\det C$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

$$\det \begin{pmatrix}
A & B \\
C & D\\
\end {pmatrix}=\det(A)\det (D-CA^{-1}B)$$
Or
$$\det \begin{pmatrix}
A & B \\
C & D\\
\end {pmatrix}
=\det(D)\det (A-BD^{-1}C).$$

To show that, suppose $A $ inversible for example and make: $\begin {pmatrix} I & 0 \\ -CA^{-1} & I \\ \end {pmatrix}\begin {pmatrix} A & B \\ C & D \\ \end {pmatrix}.$

Comment: Where did you get this  from?

Comment: I put other hint to show the first hint in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

We have $\,\det\Lambda=\det A \cdot\det C\,$ as a consequence of the formula for the computation of a determinant by blocks – a generalisation of the *Laplace formula* for the development of determinant along a row or a column.

Namely, consider the first $k$ columns of an $n\times n$ matrix $A$, and let $\varphi$ an increasing function from $[1\, ..\,k]$ to $[1\, ..\,n]$; $\varphi$ can be uniqueley extended to a permutation of  $[1\, ..\,n]$ such that its restriction to  $[k+1\, ..\,n]$ is increasing. We'll still call $\varphi$ this permutation of   $[1\, ..\,n]$.

Now for any such $\varphi$, call $\,D_\varphi=\det\bigl(a_{\varphi(i)j}\bigr)_{1\le i,j\le k}\,$ the determinant extracted from $A$ by selecting the first $f$ columns and the $k$ rows $\bigl(\varphi(1),\dots,\varphi(k)\bigr)$. Let $\,D^c_\varphi=\det\bigl(a_{\varphi(i)j}\bigr)_{k+1\le i,j\le n}$ the complementary determinant. Then we have the formula:
$$\det A=\sum_{\varphi}\varepsilon(\varphi) D_\varphi\cdot D^c_\phi $$

Here only the $k$-th principal minor $\det A$ will be non-zero, since all other $D_\varphi$ will have at least on line of $0$s, and its complementary determinant  is $\,\det C$, whence the formula.